# RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number: 3214336

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, discord.js, ejs

im trying to do a Discord Dashboard, but im getting a weird error: Invalid bitfield flag or number 3214336. This happens when im trying to get the guilds that user have MANAGE_GUILDS, my code is:

```html
<%- include("../Includes/header", { bot, path, user, Discord, title: 'Dashboard' }) %>
<div class="content">

<h2>SELECT A SERVER</h2>


<div class="servers">
<% user.guilds.forEach(guild => {
 const permsOnGuild = new Discord.Permissions(guild);
 if(!permsOnGuild.has("MANAGE_GUILD")) {
 return
 }

   if (!bot.guilds.cache.get(guild.id)) { 
    return
   } 
 if (guild.icon) {
 iconurl = "https://cdn.discordapp.com/icons/" + guild.id + "/" + guild.icon + ".png??size=512";
} else {
 iconurl = "https://cdn.glitch.com/82fe990a-7942-42e3-9790-39807ccdb9f6%2Ficon-404-dark.png?v=1602427904949";
}
%>
<div class="server">
  <div class="icon-and-name">
<img class="server-icon" src="<%= iconurl %>" alt="<% guild.name %>"/>
  <p class="guild-name"><%= guild.name %></p>
  </div>
  <% if (bot.guilds.cache.get(guild.id)) { %>
    <a class="edit button" href="/redeem/<%= guild.id %>">Redeem</a>
  <% } %>
</div>
  <% }); %>
</div>

<script>
    function PopupCenter(e, n, t, i) {
        var o = void 0 != window.screenLeft ? window.screenLeft : screen.left,
            d = void 0 != window.screenTop ? window.screenTop : screen.top,
            c = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : document.documentElement.clientWidth ? document.documentElement.clientWidth : screen.width,
            w = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : document.documentElement.clientHeight ? document.documentElement.clientHeight : screen.height,
            r = c / 2 - t / 2 + o, h = w / 2 - i / 2 + d,
            s = window.open(e, n, "scrollbars=yes, width=" + t + ", height=" + i + ", top=" + h + ", left=" + r);
        window.focus && s.focus()
    }
</script>
```

Idk why this happening, if I log "guild" I can get access to id, name, icon, owner, permissions, features and permissions_new

Answer (score 0):

Try doing

```
let permsOnGuild = new Discord.Permissions(BigInt(guild.permissions));
if (! permsOnGuild.has(Discord.Permissions.FLAGS.MANAGE_GUILD)) return;
```